# The TextView doesn't fit in the center

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I dynamically declared some horizontal layouts witch contains some elements like ImageButtons, Buttons, and TextViews, these elements centrally oriented, all of the elements are oriented perfectly but the TextViews. I tried both declaring them directly like the rest of the elements and declaring them each inside a vertical layout but both didn't work:

[image]

that's my code:

```
        // the layout params for the Horizontal Layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_icon = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
              0, 1);
        lp_icon.setMargins(10, 15, 5, 0);

        // the layout params for the elements that contained in the horizontal LinearLayout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ineer_ver = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);

        // the layout params for the TextViews
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tests = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

        // the layout params for the vertical layouts that contaion TextViews
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams temp_lay = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              0, 
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);
            temp_lay.weight = 1;


        // the elements declaration
        icon1.setLayoutParams(lp_icon);// icon1 is then horizontal LinearLayout
        icon1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ac_overlay);
        icon1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        icon1.setTag(NORMAL);

        // TextView contained in a vertical Layout
        LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(this);
        icon1.addView(lay);
        lay.setLayoutParams(temp_lay);
        lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
            lay.addView(text1);
            text1.setLayoutParams(tests);
            text1.setText("Master Bedroom");
            text1.setTextSize(12);
            text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        // other elements
        ImageButton image = new ImageButton(this);
        icon1.addView(image);
        image.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.grpbuttonfocus6);
        image.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Button testbut = new Button(this);
        icon1.addView(testbut);
        testbut.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
        testbut.setText(" 8");
        testbut.setTextSize(12);
        testbut.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        testbut.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        ImageButton testcol = new ImageButton(this);
        icon1.addView(testcol);
        testcol.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
        testcol.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_cool);
        testcol.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // the TextView that's declared directly in the Horizontal Layout
        TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
        icon1.addView(text2);
        text2.setLayoutParams(lp_ineer_ver);
        text2.setText("00");
        text2.setTextSize(12);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing it in code rather than using an XML layout file?

Comment: On an Android 4+ go to Settings > Developer Options > (Drawing) Show layout bounds, enable that option to show the bounds of each view. I suspect that the problem is the wrap content in the text view.

Comment: @BenPearson yea , i got the data of the elements in the run time

Comment: @madlymad i tried to set it a Fill_parent but also didn't work

Comment: @MRefaat can you add a photo of the screen with the layout bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Juse two changes in your code like below for first textview `icon1.addView(text1);` and the last textview  `text2.setLayoutParams(tests);`

First

```
        TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
        icon1.addView(text1);              //correction here
        text1.setLayoutParams(tests);
        text1.setText("Master Bedroom");
        text1.setTextSize(12);
```

and Second

```
    TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
    icon1.addView(text2);
    text2.setLayoutParams(tests);   //correction here
    text2.setText("00");
    text2.setTextSize(12);
```

Comment: where's your changes ?

Comment: @MRefaat in 1st `icon1` instead of `lay` and 2nd `tests` instead of `lp_ineer_ver`

Comment: but i tried that before, as I said I made the two layouts once declared from the vertical one and once declared directly, so the first one was declared directly from 'icon1' but it didn't work then.

Comment: WoW, it works with the first TextView, so i declared the second with the same way and it also worked, pretty sure i'm tried that before :D

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

and you can have Try adding the following code for applying the layout params to the TextView

```
LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(LinearLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

in XML file :

android:gravity = "center"

Comment: I didn't declare them in the XML as i'm getting the data at the run time